# UWP project added to Xamarin is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms app (only doing things for Android now) where I added a project from an UWP app. With this, I get two erros which I cannot solve. I've found some things on the internet, but nothing for my specific situation.

The erros are:

Project UWP.Project is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0).
Project UWP.Project supports: uap10.0.17763 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17763).

Project UWP.Project is not compatible with monoandroid11.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0).
Project UWP.Project supports: uap10.0.17763 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17763).

How do I solve this?

Comment: How did you added the new project ? You might be referencing the android project from your UWP, but you only need to reference the shared code

Comment: I just added the existing project to my solution and then I went to Reference Manager to hit the checkbox in the Projects section. The Shared Projects section is empty.

Comment: But which projects are checked in the reference list? Each platform project references the Core (shared) project, but they never reference each other

Comment: Well I have only the Android project and the added project in this list. I cannot add the Android project as a reference since that will lead to a circular dependency, so only the added project is checked.

Comment: But do you also have the shared project?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Xamarin.Forms app (only doing things for Android now) where I added a project from an UWP app.

It looks you need to update the UWP project target version to 17763. For adding the new platform for existing Forms app, you may refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/connect/xamarin-xamarin-and-the-universal-windows-platform#add-a-uwp-project-to-your-existing-xamarinforms-app). And please note making the following changes to UWP MainPage.xaml

```
Inside the <Page> tag, add: xmlns:forms=“using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP
```